# Need to import mail but cannot execute Evolution

Tags: evolution

My 11.10 installation is broken (long story) and I cannot boot to it.  I have installed 12.04 on a separate partition, and can mount the drive containing my old Evolution files.

What I want to do is:
Import all the data from my Old (11.10) evolution location (`~/.local/john/share/evolution` is the location I've seen in other posts, but I'm not sure which sub-folders I need) into evolution on the new (12.04) partition.  Since the old OS is totally hosed, I can't boot to it in order to use Evolution's functionality to export and move folders around, etc, like I've seen in other posts.

Any suggestions on how I can rescue all the emails and contains from the old location would be greatly appreciated!

PS.  I have a POP account and a Gmail account at the old install. The Gmail I'm not too worried about, but the pop mail is no longer on my ISP server, so I need a way to save it from the old location.

**edit:**  I don't care whether I end up with evolution or Thunderbird as a result - whichever will work to import or migrate the old emails.

Comment: Although it's outdated, have you given this documentation a try? - [Migrate Evolution To a New Computer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateEvolutionToNewComputer)

Comment: Using the above method from Live Usb or Live cd would be better.

Comment: @nitstorm, if you rephrase as an answer, I'll mark as the correct choice.  The folder was actually ~/.local/share/evolution for my installation but the gist was the same.  Appreciate it!

Comment: @JohnKeller Thanks, done :) Please do feel free to edit the answer if you did something else to fix it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is an excerpt from the [Ubuntu Community Documentation for Migrating Evolution to a New Computer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateEvolutionToNewComputer) with a slight modification according to your installation:

> ***Procedure***
>
> 1. Run these two commands on both the source and the target computer (these stop the programs that might interfere with your
>      copy):
>
>    ```
>    gconftool-2 --shutdown
>
>    evolution --force-shutdown
>    ```
> 2. Copy the directories `~/.local/share/evolution`, `~/.gconf/apps/evolution` and `~/.gnome2_private/Evolution` from the
>      source computer to the same place on the target computer.
> 3. Start Evolution on the target computer (this will automatically start the programs that you stopped in step 1).
>
> *Note: Take care not to start any Gnome applications between steps 1 and 2, as these will automatically restart the programs that you want
>   to have stopped.*